# Scraping text from doc and docx files in one function

Tags: python, docx, doc, python-docx

I am iterating over a list of urls that link to docx, doc and pdf files. I wrote a function that allows me to extract the text from docx files and append it to a new list. I have no interest in the pdf files, but I would also like to extract the text from the doc files in the same function.

After some research it seems that `textract` is recommended by most people to download docx and doc files. However, I can not run it properly on my device and would like to find a different solution.

I've tried to convert every doc file to docx, but it became to cumbersome (for me) to include in the function.

This is how the function looks right now. It downloads all files and extracts the text of the docx files in a list. 'Empty' otherwise.

```
import os.path
import urllib.request
import os
import requests
import docx2txt

l = []
for link in urls:
    link = link.strip()
    name = link.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
    filename = os.path.join(name)
    quoted_url = urllib.parse.quote(link, safe=":/")

    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        print('Downloading: ' + filename)
        try:
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(quoted_url, filename)
            try:
                file = docx2txt.process(filename)
                file = file.replace('\n', ' ')
                file = file.replace('\t', ' ')
                l.append(file)
            except:
                print('  no docx file')
                l.append('empty')
        except Exception as inst:
            print(inst)
            print('  Encountered error. Continuing.')
            l.append('empty')
```

The expected output would be to extract text from doc and docx files in the list and 'empty' otherwise (for pdfs or bad links).

Comment: Is there a technology reason you need to have everything in one function? If not, I would suggest three different helper functions for each file type. You could then check the file extension within the main function call and use whichever helper function was appropriate for the file type

Comment: Not necessarily. However, I must keep the order of the links when appending text to the new list. I thought there must be an easy way to do this in python (just as extracting docx is only one line). Do you have a suggestion to efficiently obtain the text from the doc files in the same fashion and append it to the list?

Answer (score 0):

Below code read .doc files:

```
import win32com.client

word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.visible = False
wb = word.Documents.Open("myfile.doc")
file= word.ActiveDocument
l.append(file.Range().Text)
```

In your code, 1st check for file extension, if it is `.docx.` then run your code then `elif` it is `.doc` then run above code and `pass` if it is `.pdf`

Comment: Thank you @Rahul. If I am not mistaken, this only works on Windows though, right? I work on macOS Mojave.

Comment: In that case, just modify your approach, if you see extension as `.doc` then change it to `.docx` and if not simply do what you do

Comment: Do you suggest to convert them in python to docx and overwrite the old saved file, or to simply change the extension of the string by adding a 'x'? Would this possibly work?

Comment: the 1st one...using python to convert `.doc` to `.docx` and delete the .doc file